# Electrical issues: where are the grounds on a 1997 vw golf mk3 tdi

Tags: electrical, vw, golf

When I have the ignition switched on, if I press the brake pedal, or use the headlights, the foglight gets turned on.

I think this is an earthing issues so I have checked the grounds in the two light clusters at the back, but I am not sure where the headlight clusters are grounded, or what else to check.

EDIT : I remade the main earth on the engine, and now the problem only affects the indicators. So the foglight blinks with the indicators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly sounds like an earthing issue, but I doubt it would be in the headlight clusters - I'd expect it to be in the rear lamp clusters somewhere.

IIRC the Golf has a combined tail and brake lamp, so both filaments will use a common ground. Generally rear clusters earth through a pressed metal frame that forms part of the bulb holders (as the bulbs return through their shells, and a single connection to the car body shell.

Comment: That was my first thought also, so I checked and remade both grounds on the rear light clusters. This didn't solve the problem though.

Comment: Found it! The earth tab on the rear left light cluster connecter had burned almost through. I remade it by soldering a new wire to the earth connection inside and connecting it to the rest of the earth wire.